# Should gulp.js plugins be inside package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp

So far in my build I haven't had a need for using package.json, since I been downloading each plugin for gulp directly ex `npm install gulp-jshint` (gulp plugins were the only node modules I was using, now I have a need for node to use express(and more), express says they should be inside package.json). However I have been using a bower.json file to get project packages like jquery and backbone etc.

So from my understanding package.json works kind of like the bower.json except it's used mainly for node modules/plugins, is that correct?

Id like to know if the above is correct, that kind of helps lead into this next question. Should I include all the gulpjs plugins inside the "dependencies"? Were the tutorials kind of a quick dirty way of explaining how to get the gulpjs plugins, it feels like those plugins should be inside a package.json, right?

**Edit:** So looking at this boilerplate it looks like they include gruntjs plugins

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Brian Frichette",
  "homepage": "",
  "contributors": [ "Brian Frichette <brian.frichette@gmail.com> (https://github.com/brian-frichette)" ],
  "bugs": { "url": "" },
  "scripts": { "start": "nodemon app.js" },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "jade": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*",
    "lodash": "1.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.x",
    "karma": ">=0.8",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": ">=0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": ">=0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": ">=0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": ">=0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": ">=0.6",
    "async": "0.1.x",
    "nodemon": "*"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "repository": "",
  "licenses": [{
    "type": "MIT",
    "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So from my understanding package.json works kind of like the
>   bower.json except it's used mainly for node modules/plugins, is that
>   correct?

Yes. Bower.js is for front-end dependencies and node.js would be for your server/development dependencies.

---

When you install your gulp dependencies you should use the `--save-dev` flag so that they're installed in your package.json under the `devDependencies` section (it will be created).

```
npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev
```

Comment: Cool I left out `--save-dev` in hopes someone would point it out that it is actually important and explain it, perfect! So package.json is associated with node, correct.

Comment: It's definitely useful to separate dependencies from devDependencies for deployment/build purposes. The devDependencies are the ones that don't have to be packaged with the applcation.... for devs/development process only.

Comment: Just tested it out using `npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev` and it added it inside my package.json automatically, this is so cool! Wish I caught this earlier, must have missed it in the articles I read.

Comment: You can also use `--save` or `-s` to add to `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`.